# Pulling data from a PDF

Tags: pdf, data

I am wondering if it is possible for SharePoint to pull information from a PDF file?

Basically, I have a document library where people can upload PDF vouchers which then get routed to different people based on the dollar amount of them. This would be fine, but we are currently entering the dollar amount into the amount column of the library manually. This has caused some issues. So, is there a way to automatically pull the dollar amount from the PDF and populate the amount column?

[image: Example]

Comment: if the pdf contains plain text you can try itextsharp. if its an image, you will need some kind of ocr solution